# Alert Message Not Rendering In Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to create message before submitting the page, but i do not know why the message not rendering , can anyone help me to correct it.

form.py

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
   translated_names = TranslationField()

class Meta:
  fields = "__all__"
  model = models.Name
```

admin.py

```
class NameAdmin(MasterDataBaseAdmin):
  form = forms.NameForm
  inlines = [AddressInline, RegistrationTypeInline]
  queryset = models.Name.objects.prefetch_related(
    "names", "name__id", "registrationstype")
```

views.py

```
class NameViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
   queryset = models.Name.objects.supported().prefetch_related("names", 
   "registrationstype")
    serializer_class = serializers.NameSerializer

 def nametype(request):
   form = Form(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
     return render(request, 'templates\ view2.html', form)
```

view2.html

```html
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.name', function(){
return confirm('Are you sure you want to update this?');
})
</script>
```

Comment: You want to add confirm dialog before sending form?

Comment: Hi , Yes , i want to add "Confirm Before Submitting"

Answer (score 1):

check the class name in your view2.html

Comment: I changed the name , that was a writing mistake, but changing the class name did not solve the my issue.

Answer (score 1):

at your  tag add
`<form onsubmit="return confirm('Are you sure you want to update this?');">`

Comment: i have to add the line in the html file right?

Comment: yes you have somwhere in view2.html tag for form : <form> you just add there onsubmit